# Automatically reopen questions with an accepted answer in some circumstances

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Some questions are in this situation:

- They have an accepted answer written by someone else than the OP
- They are closed under the motive "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."

Indeed some questions are poorly written, but we must agree that all humans are not equal when it comes to understanding what ask with the wrong words or in a clumsy way.

In the situation described above, at least one person was able to understand the question and provide a helpful answer. So maybe an other person will come across the same question and find the answer he/she was looking. This is why I think the question should remain open in this situation.

I agree that the quality of the question is important to the site, but there is also a way to "punish" a poorly written question: downvote, so there is no need to add closing the question while it has still a chance to fulfill it's role.

**Edit:** I understand now that there would be a huge flaw in this feature: you could just accept any answer just for the pleasure of not having their question closed... but I didn't think about that flaw in the first place.

Comment: I'd rather see the question reopened because the question is good enough. Not because a user managed to magically guess what was meant. If anything, given his understanding and the acceptance of his answer, he could edit the question to clarify it and see it reopened.

Comment: I don't understand: *"an accepted answer from someone else than the OP"*. How's that?

Comment: other feature request: allow negative reputation on meta for more noob bashing ;=)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the answer actually does solve the OP's problem, then there isn't much value to reopening the question anyway. If it's still unclear, it's unlikely to get additional good answers, and it sounds like the OP is satisfied.

*However*, there is a potential for abuse. Someone could simply accept an answer that doesn't solve their problem because they heard it would get their question automatically reopened, at which point they hope it will get another answer. (And what happens if they then unaccept the answer? Should the question automatically become closed again?)

Answer (score 9):

If a question is poorly written enough to get five close votes, which situation is more likely from the perspective of someone searching through Google:

- The question and answer are just what they're looking for.
- The question is a waste of time and they regret clicking it.

I'd place around 5:1 odds on the latter.  The question can still be reopened, it just needs to be improved first.

Comment: But closed questions with an accepted answer are very rare. If you want to optimise ability to find good questions/answers on google, displaying the number of upvote in the search result entry would be more useful, because it would: 1/ reflect the majority opinion better, 2/ Affect a very large number of question